# VS 2012 (Visual C ): error C2143: syntax error: miss ";" before "*"

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2012

I have this error at "iterator_of_array_int.h":

```
#include "array_of_int.h"
#include <cstdlib>    
namespace leonidandand {
    class iterator_of_array_int
    {           
    private:
        std::size_t index;
        // next line has error
        array_of_int * ptr_to_arr;
        friend class array_of_int;
    };
}
```

"array_of_int.h"

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdlib>
#include "iterator_of_array_int.h"
namespace leonidandand {
    class array_of_int {
    public:    
        typedef iterator_of_array_int iterator;
        iterator_of_array_int begin();
        iterator_of_array_int end();
    };
}
```

I included "array_of_int.h". What's wrong???

Comment: What's inside "array_of_int.h"?

Comment: It might be that array_of_int is in a namespace other than that of the iterator?

Comment: *"I included "array_of_int.h"."* -- I don't supposed you'd mind including it in your question as well?

Comment: @WhozCraig that made me LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You included `array_of_int.h` which, before defining `array_of_int`, included `iterator_of_array_int.h`.  So when the compiler sees your error line, it hasn't seen any declaration of the name `array_of_int`.  The error message isn't one of the more helpful ones issued by a compiler.

I'm in the habit of forward-declaring classes in headers; that's all you need in `iterator_of_array_int.h`, so replace the `include` line with `class array_of_int;` and that one's good.

Answer (score 3):

Normally that error means it doesnt recognise the type you put before the ' * '

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your **array_of_int** struct / class definition on array_of_int.h, check you have semicolon at the end of the definition. It seems that type is not properly recognized by the compiler